# Active Directory Global Address Book

Tags: active-directory, exchange

How can I setup up a global address book in AD to pull from the email field within a OU? I've got a OU called, Workstation Users. In that OU, I have 20-30 users that have the email field filled in. I would like to add a global address book to my Outlook users where this list will autopopulate, and sync whenever I add a new user to the OU, or delete a user.

Comment: There isn't any native functionality to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out.

1. Enter email address for each user in the email field within that users properties inside ADUC that I want to populate in the address book.
2. Make a user account to use for AD authentication. I put mine in my Managed Users OU.
3. On my users machines with Outlook installed, add a LDAP address book. Point it to a domain controller, enter the credentials for the managed users account I created in step 2.
4. Make sure browsing is enabled, and leave the search base as default. It will find all email addresses inside AD that have something entered in the email address field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Exchange, and I am not sure if you are or not going by your question, you can just add a new address list in Exchange.  In the address list add a rule and point it to the OU that you want to scope to.

You can do this in 2013/2016.  As far as I can recall you can also do it in 2010, but I don't have 2010 in my org to verify against.  I am also pretty sure that if you still have a 2007 or older server in your org it will give you an error if you try to scope an address list to an OU.